# Header and footer are hiding while scrolling the page in blackberry phonegap application

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry

I have developed a Phonegap application for Blackberry platform. I had an issue is that while scrolling the page, the header and footer are hiding in Blackberry Phonegap application.

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Considering adding some screen shots and code to clarify your question and make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: You should post a snippet of code where your problem is and write in detail what happens,so people can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent vertical manager where the header and footer is placed as

```java
NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL|NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR
```

while all the rest of the data should be placed inside a seperate vertical manager (v1) which is

```java
VerticalFieldManager vr1 = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
```

and this in turn is placed inside the parent vertical manager;

```java
verticalManager.add(vr1);
```

If you post your code, the answer can be explained better.